# oracle regexp_like with pattern from select

Tags: sql, oracle, pls-00428

I try to select rows from a table using a regex. The pattern is the result of a select. 

I have the following compilation error on the select that use regexp_like:

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

```
declare 
  pattern varchar2;

begin

  select columns
  into pattern
  from table a
  where conditions;

  select * 
  from table2 
  where regexp_like(column, pattern);

end;
```

I don't understand why I should use an into clause...

Comment: SELECT in plsql should have a INTO clause. You have already used it in your 1st statement.

Comment: Your statement
 "select * from table2 where regexp_like(column, pattern); "
 also should have a INTO clause like the first one.

Why do you need this statement anyway? are u using the o/p of this second select statement anywhere?

Comment: I would use the second select as this : update my_table
set col = value
where col2 in 
(
select * 
from table2 
where regexp_like(column, pattern)
)

Comment: If you are going to use plain sql statement without INTO clause then simply you can use execute('sql statement') or execute immediate('sql statement');

Comment: You have only one column in table2? 'where col2 in (select col2..)' it should be like this

Comment: Yes, it is 'where col2 in (select col2..)'. If I use execute immediate, I get '"pattern": invalid identifier'.

Comment: I forgot the "using" statement with execute immediate. It works now. Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an obvious bug in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution is:

```
declare

  pattern varchar2;

begin

  select columns
  into pattern
  from table a
  where conditions;


  execute immediate '
      select col2 
      from table2 
      where regexp_like(column, :pattern)
  ' using pattern;

end;
```

Thanks!